# addClass function working properly but removeClass function not working on input text field for form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Creating an Online form and I'd like only the field that the user is focused on to be notfaded so i decided to add some jQuery to my form but the remove class function is not working. addClass works when I click into a field it shows brightly and not faded as it adds the Focused class but as soon as I click away or am no longer focused on that field the Focused class remains.

I've seen some similar posts but the solutions on the other posts don't seem to pertain to my issue. 
Below is my form

```
<form name="contactform" method="post"> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 inputFaded">
<span class="larger"><strong>Name</strong> <span class="textGreen">*</span></span><br><br>
<span>Please provide your full name</span>
<input type="text" maxlength="100" class="form-control discuss" name="projectname">
<br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="submit" name="nameaction" value="SEND" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Below is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="text"]').on('focus', function() {
       $('.inputFaded').addClass('Focused');
   });

   $('input[type="text"]').off('focus', function() {
       $('.inputFaded').removeClass('Focused');
   });
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: I think you need to use the blur event:                              
$('input[type="text"]').on('blur", function() {
    $('.inputFaded').removeClass('Focused');
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

> Description: Remove an event handler.

So it seems that you need to listen [`focusin`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focusin.asp) and [`focusout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focusout.asp) event.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="text"]').focusin(function() {
    $('.inputFaded').addClass('Focused');
});

$('input[type="text"]').focusout(function() {
    $('.inputFaded').removeClass('Focused');
});
});
```

```css
.Focused{
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="contactform" method="post"> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 inputFaded">
<span class="larger"><strong>Name</strong> <span class="textGreen">*</span></span><br><br>
<span>Please provide your full name</span>
<input type="text" maxlength="100" class="form-control discuss" name="projectname">
<br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="submit" name="nameaction" value="SEND" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Updated**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').focusin(function() {
        $(this).addClass('Focused');
    });

    $('input[type="text"]').focusout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('Focused');
    });
});
```

```css
.Focused{
   border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="contactform" method="post"> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 inputFaded">
<span class="larger"><strong>Name</strong> <span class="textGreen">*</span></span><br><br>
<span>Please provide your full name</span>
<input type="text" maxlength="100" class="form-control discuss" name="projectname">
<br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="submit" name="nameaction" value="SEND" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up @Phong I've run into another issue now though, the solution appears to add the class when I focus on any input field of type text. I obviously haven't had time to look around about this but is this becuase the jQuery will apply to all input fields rather than just the one i'm focusing on?

Comment: If you want to listen each input that you are focusing on, you can change from `$('.inputFaded')` to `$('this')`

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look @Chunks

Comment: Good tip @Phong if you don't mind me asking how would you add the 'Focused' class to the <div class="col-md-12 inputFaded"> element instead of how now $this is adding 'Focused' to the input element classes. In short I am trying to have the entire column faded until focused.

Comment: you are being awesome in all of this. However I think I am failing at asking my question. Earlier you mention that I should change ('.inputFaded') to (this) so that i only focus on the input field that I click on and none others. However that was adding my .Focused class to the wrong element e.g. the input element classes rather than adding and removing the class from my <div class="col-md-6 inputFaded"> element. I want to do the fade in fade out but only fade in the column/input I am currently on which makes me think i need (this) You've more than helped so I understand if you are done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206677/discussion-between-phong-and-chunks).

Answer (score 1):

The `.off` function is not used for running a function but for removing a function from an Event tied to an element, as already pointed out by @Phong. Instead use the `.focusout()` function or `.on("focusout", ..)`

Please note that if this is also quite simple in Vanilla JS:

```
// Vanilla JS solution
(function(){
  let input = document.querySelector("input[type='text']"),
      inputFaded = document.querySelector(".inputFaded");

  input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    console.log("focused now!");
    inputFaded.classList.add('Focused');
  });

  input.addEventListener('focusout', function(){
    console.log("I will also be run! :)");
    inputFaded.classList.remove('Focused');
  })
})()
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').on('focus', function() {
        console.log("focused now!");
        $('.inputFaded').addClass('Focused');
    });

    // Removing function from focus event that does not exist as a function to an eventlistener
    $('input[type="text"]').off('focus', function() {
        console.log("I will never be run? :(");
        $('.inputFaded').removeClass('Focused');
    });
    
    // adding focusout eventlistener
    $('input[type="text"]').on('focusout', function() {
        console.log("I will be run! :)");
        $('.inputFaded').removeClass('Focused');
    });
    
    // alternative way of adding focusout eventlistener
    $('input[type="text"]').focusout( function() {
        console.log("I will also be run! :)");
        $('.inputFaded').removeClass('Focused');
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="contactform" method="post"> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 inputFaded">
<span class="larger"><strong>Name</strong> <span class="textGreen">*</span></span><br><br>
<span>Please provide your full name</span>
<input type="text" maxlength="100" class="form-control discuss" name="projectname">
<br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="submit" name="nameaction" value="SEND" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").focus(function(){
    $('.inputFaded').addClass('Focused');
  });

   $("input").on('blur', function() {
    $('div').removeClass('Focused');
  });

});
```